# Decorator overwriting POST, GET and REQUEST in Django - doing it right?

Tags: python, django, decorator

In Django, I have created a function decorator which can - in this example - create a lowercase version of a supplied POST/GET argument, and it updates the REQUEST before the view handles it all. 
I have created the following decorator for this:

```
def force_lowercase(*fields):
    assert isinstance(fields, tuple), "Fields must be of type tuple."

    def wrap_func(fn):
       def wrapper(request):
           post = request.POST.copy()
           get  = request.GET.copy()
           for field in fields:
               if field in post:
                   post[field] = post[field].lower()
               if field in get:
                   get[field]  = get[field].lower()

           request._post = post   
           request._get = get
           request._request = MergeDict(post,get)

           return fn(request)
       return wrapper
   return wrap_func
```

In my view I would have something like:

```
@force_lowercase(email,zipcode)
def index(request)
    #blabla
```

Is this the proper way to do this? I'm a bit concerned I hack Django's WSGIRequest object in such a way, other Django functionality might not see the updated GET/POST/REQUEST objects.

Comment: You could think about developing a middleware which intercepts the request post and get data, modifiy those and pass them to the underlying functions.

Comment: @Jingo: I thought about that, but I don't always want to modify the data. Also, I want to be able to specify which fields should be targeted per function in a view. ..... Made me think of that meme guy: "I don't always modify data, but when I do, I acquire my target with optimal precision" :P

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a form, you could do the lowercase in the form itself.

While the implementation works IMO, I have a problem that for every single call, you end up copying the get/post dictionaries, searching through them, converting the fields and appending the result back as `request._request` which you need to know about to be able to use it. I think it's a bit of overkill...

I'd change it with a simple method called in the view (depending on your situation, you can either overwrite the original values with the lowercase ones or create new elements).

Another solution can be to do it in the HTML page via javascript. You can either (hard)code the template, create a custom widget, or use something like an attribute specified in the widget plus a jquery call...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm building some sort of backend system which will not have its own forms, and I have numerous views which work with lowercase-only input. Readability and re-usability wise, a decorator seemed the best option for me. I use the decorator in more modules in my app.

Comment: I've got two concerns about the decorator; 1. The processing overhead (as above) and 2. the risk that you may have flavors of it later. I'd go with a rule of the thumb on this: if there are lots of places where you can use it, then write a decorator. Otherwise, try to do it explicit in the view.

Comment: I am using it on lots of places... so the rule of thumb will apply here :-) However, I just notice I constantly overwrite POST/GET/REQUEST in this example, will fix indentation as it is in my IDE.

Comment: OK :). Then, instead of copying the whole post/get dictionaries, you could either overwrite the original ones from `request` or create new fields (either in a dict or in the original). I'm thinking that if you have a form with a lot of fields, or some large textareas, the decorator may take longer than the actual logic. You can also split it in two decorators (a get and a post) and use them as needed.

Comment: The issue is that you cannot directly overwrite the keys, it throws an ImmutableDict error :-)

Comment: Oops, that's unfortunate... Then, I think the current code is OK. One thing: wouldn't `post[field].lower()` throw an exception if the field is not there? I think it's [KeyError](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict). you may want to use `post.get(field, '').lower()` instead.

Comment: Thats why I check using `if field in post`, I don't want to add a key which wasn't there :). Thanks for your response.